# How can I add multiple requirements sets to the manifest.xml file for an Office add-in?

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins, excel-web-addins, word-web-addins

I have an Office add-in that works for Word, Excel and PowerPoint, but I want it to only be available for Office 2021 onwards (Windows Desktop)

I found that it is possible using Requirement Sets, but when I specify 3, the validator (office- addin-manifest) returns an error message:

Error #1:
No Supported Office Products: There are no platforms which fulfil the requirements specified in the manifest. The most common reasons for this failure are issues in the Requirements section. Please review the manifest and try again.

The manifest is not valid.

[image]

When I specify only one Requirement set, the file passes validation
[image]

[image]

Comment: This looks like a bug. Please create an issue on the [office-js repo](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/new/choose).

Comment: Thank you @RickKirkham for taking the time to answer this, I'll create an issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

The Office add-ins team is working on supporting multiple hosts in the single add-in manifest. I suppose for that reasons the validation tool is not fully adapted for the validation process of such manifests. Try to post this to https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues and hopefully that will be supported soon.

Comment: Thank you Eugene for taking the time to answer this, I'll create an issue on GitHub

Comment: Don't forget to share the link to your post here. It can be useful for other readers.

Comment: This is the link to the issue on github:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/4179